# Use define fixed size rotated SVG symbol controlled by Atlas

Tags: qgis-3, atlas, mapping, north-arrow

I'm working with QGIS 3.10 under FreeBSD 12.1 and trying to use a North direction SVG arrow symbol which is controlled by an atlas. The atlas is driven by a set of map sheets arranged along a winding corridor.

[image: example1]

Each sheet has a fixed size and scale as well as the map is turned into a axis parallel chart by the sheet (atlas driven). For each sheet I defined a North arrow rotation parameter corresponding to map rotation (`"Composer -> Item Properties -> North Arrow -> Image rotation"`).

[image: example2]

Unfortunately the size of the North arrow is automatically adopted for each rotation due to the corresponding rotated angular dependent bounding box (`"Main Properties -> Resize Mode"`).

**Example North Direction**

[image: example3]

**Example North-East Direction**

[image: example4]

If I use of main `"Properties -> Clip"` (which I guess is the right parameter for a circular symbol which is centered an cannot be clipped), the rotation by the atlas is turned off.

Which parameter do I've to use get a rotated equal sized atlas controlled symbol under the `"Composer -> Item Properties -> North Arrow"` dialog.

Comment: Which is the parameter that you are using to change the orientation of the maps in the Atlas?

Comment: I've calculated a turn angle (with angular range control to prevent upside-down flipping) held in the attribute table for each sheet (SHEET.ANGLE_B). The ATLAS is controlled and sorted by the SHEET.ID. And the map is turned "Item Properties->Main Properties"->"Map Rotation" -> Expression(ANGLE_B)  of the coverage layer (SHEET).

Comment: Ok. Try removing the sinc with the map in the Image orientation of the north arrow and use the same parameter in the *Rotation* as a variable. I tried to replicate your issue and seems to me that using this second way the arrow doesn't change in size. You can use in the expression the variable * @atlas_featureid * to recall the page.

Comment: Thanks VAL P that works fine for me. As you supposed I the removed "Image rotation -> sync" and use ( "North Arrow" -> "Item Properties -> "Rotation" -> EXPRESSION( ANGLE_B ) to get proper result. Could you provide an answer so I can mark "solve" for the question and upvote your answer?

Comment: Happy that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you can change the way to orientate the North arrow.

Considering that you are using a parameter to change the orientation of the pages of your Atlas, in the *Item Proprieties* of the north arrow, instead using the option *Image Rotation > Sinc with map*, try to use the option *Rotation*.

With the *Sync with map* option off, go in *Rotation* and here use as a variable the same parameter used for orientate the Atlas pages.

[image]

In the expression you can use the variable * @atlas_featureid * to recall the Atlas pages (and them ID).

In this way the north arrow change the orientation according with the page orientation without change in size.